# MySQL return all results without duplicating data

Tags: php, mysql, str-replace, explode

This is my data

```
id          cost    cat         foreign     colours
--------------------------------------------------------   
385_white   99      swarovski   12          black;blue
386_white   99      swarovski   12          black;blue;green
387_white   99      swarovski   12          yellow;green
389_white   99      swarovski   12          white;silver
385_white   99      swarovski   12          silver
```

This is my query

```
$checkSQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products`");
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkSQL)) {

    echo '<ul class="ColourList">';
    $cols = explode( ';', $r['colours'] );
    foreach ( $cols as $col ){
        echo '<li class="' . $col . '">' . $col . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

This basically returns a list of colors for each record

```
<ul>
 <li>black</li>
 <li>blue</li>
</ul>
```

However I want to return a single list, for every color i the entire database and alphabetize it. So basically get all the colors, in all rows, split them in a list in ABC order but without them repeating - is this possible with my clients setup? Just need some direction? Thinking `explode` with `replace` and then us the `ORDER BY ASC` command?

Comment: Is DB normalization allowed? If so, I suggest to create two new tables: `colors(colorId, colorName)` and `products_colors(productId, colorId)` to relate products and available colors.

Comment: the best is to use proper entity relationship, no a string :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nice example of what happens if you **not normalize** your database. At first it seems easy, but ones runs into trouble later.

Change your tables like this:

Products:

```
id          cost    cat         foreign     
--------------------------------------------   
385_white   99      swarovski   12
```

ProductColors:

```
id          color_id     
----------------------
385_white   1                
385_white   2
```

Colors:

```
id          name     
----------------------
1           Black     
2           Blue
```

If you have a structure like this, it is very easy ro query the database for what you want.

Example:

To query all available colors:

```
select * from colors
```

To query all available colors for `385_white`:

```
select * from productcolors where id = '385_white'
```

Comment: This is what we have ended up doing. Basically normalizing the data. It would be interesting to see the solution anyway to have done this.

Comment: You would be ending up crawling to endless amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL is run once so this

> Thinking explode with replace and then us the ORDER BY ASC command?

Cannot be done.

Try this SQL

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY colours GROUP BY colours
```

This will order by colours alphabetically, and then group by colours will remove the duplicates you are talking of.

You should also restructure your data into a one to many relationship for colours, using the `;` as a separator is no good and you will get real headaches later on.

Comment: The `GROUP BY colours` clause will not remove duplicates. For example the following values are different and create colours duplicates: `black;blue` and `black;blue;green`

Comment: Given the moronic nature of the table, its the best the OP is going to get.

Comment: @ADC What we have ended up doing is basically normalizing the data. It would be interesting to see the solution anyway to have done this

Answer (score 0):

If you often have to run queries on and about your 'colours' field (other than a simple SELECT * for raw displaying), that means that your field should be designed to be easily queriable.

This means : don't store multiple entries inside 1 fields, it will make your life hard everytime you need to query and extract things.

Instead, create a  '**colours**' table (colour_id, colour_name)

and an '**articlecolors**' table (article_id, colour_id).

This way every article can still have multiple colors, and it gets much easier to add new colors.
And you will be able to run any query about articles colors using standard SQL : retrieving a list of colours without duplicates will be as easy as 'SELECT DISTINCT(colour_name) FROM colours'